# Golang http.Get()

Tags: http, go, server

I'm trying to write a basic http server example. I can curl `localhost:8080`, but can't contact the server with `http.Get("127.0.0.1:8080")` from the client script. What am I doing wrong?

server.go:

```
import "fmt"
import "net/http"

func join(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("Someone joined")
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Listening on port 8080...")
    http.HandleFunc("/join", join)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

client.go:

```
import "net/http"
http.Get("127.0.0.1:8080/join")
```

Comment: "I [...] can't contact the server" is not a helpful description of what actual problem you are facing. BTW: capturing and handling the error from http.Get would be informative here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `http.Get("http://127.0.0.1:8080/join")`. Note the "http:".  Also, check the error. It will tell you what the problem is.

```
resp, err := http.Get("http://127.0.0.1:8080/join")
if err != nil {
  log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Comment: hey, say if i dont want to use `err` in my code how can i replace `resp, err := http.Get("http://127.0.0.1:8080/join")` with something like `response_struct := http.Get("http://127.0.0.1:8080/join")` ?

Answer (score 2):

You have't specified the scheme, try `http.Get("http://127.0.0.1:8080/join")`

`http.Get` like many other go functions return the error so if you have written your code you like:

```
_, err := http.Get("127.0.0.1:8080/join")
if err != nil{
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

you would have seen:

```
Get 127.0.0.1:8080/join: unsupported protocol scheme ""
```